# How to check React Native Elements Native Props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to toggle a view in react native without using setState and i had to make two functions for that
1: to hide the View
2: to show the View

**showViewMethod**

```
this.speedControlBox.setNativeProps({style: {display:'flex'}});
```

**hideViewMethod**

```
this.speedControlBox.setNativeProps({style: {display:'none'}});
```

Now i want you to help me that how can i make these two functions into one that i can check is view style display is flex or none.

Comment: why don't u just pass extra params in function call, and based on that u can do hide or unhide the view

Comment: yes i just did that thanks for suggestion